# How to group things in Looker Studio with "but not" condition?

Tags: case, grouping, looker-studio

In Looker Studio I have two types of urls, which I want to group. URLs are categories and articles looking like:

```
https://example.com/category1/
https://example.com/category1/article_abc
https://example.com/category2/
https://example.com/category2/article_xyz
```

I thought about using in the CASE a kind of the following expression:

```
CASE

WHEN URL ENDS_WITH "category1/" THEN "category1 folder"
WHEN URL COMTAINS "category1" BUT NOT ENDS_WITH "category1/" THEN "category1 url"

END
```

But I'm pretty sure, that this part with `BUT NOT`will not work. What is the right way? Should I maybe make USE of `REGEX_MATCH`? Like

```
CASE

WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(URL, "category1\/$") THEN "category1 folder" 
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(URL, "category1\/.+?") THEN "category1 url" 

END
```

Comment: `REGEXP_MATCH` requires a whole string match. You do not need the regex here, since at any rate it is RE2 and it does not support lookarounds.  Mind that`BUT NOT` = `AND NOT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(URL, "category1/$") THEN "category1 folder" 
WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(URL, "category1/.+") THEN "category1 url"
END
```

[image]